# JMS 2 MDB listen to multiple queue

Tags: java, jms, websphere-liberty, open-liberty, jms2

I use JavaEE 8 on Liberty 18.0.0.2 .
I setup jms activation config like this (server.xml):

```
  <messagingEngine>
    <queue id="application" />
  </messagingEngine>
  <jmsActivationSpec id="app/appMDB">
    <properties.wasJms destinationRef="java:app/onlineQueue" />
  </jmsActivationSpec>
```

And this is my simple MDB message listener :

```
@MessageDriven(
        name = "appMDB",
        mappedName = "java:app/onlineQueue",
        activationConfig = {
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
                        propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
                @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",
                        propertyValue = "java:app/onlineQueue")
        }
)
public class ApplicationMessageListener implements MessageListener {
...
}
```

And also I defined two queues like this :

```
@Stateless
@JMSDestinationDefinitions(
        value = {
                @JMSDestinationDefinition(
                        name = "java:app/onlineQueue",
                        interfaceName = "javax.jms.Queue",
                        destinationName = "application"),
                @JMSDestinationDefinition(
                        name = "java:app/offlineQueue",
                        interfaceName = "javax.jms.Queue",
                        destinationName = "application")
        }
)
public class MessageService {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:app/onlineQueue")
    private Queue onlineQueue;

    @Resource(lookup = "java:app/offlineQueue")
    private Queue offlineQueue;

    @Inject
    private JMSContext context;

    @EJB
    private MessageUtils messageUtils;

    public void sendToOnlineQueue(SimpleMessage simpleMessage) {
        TextMessage message = messageUtils.createTextMessage(simpleMessage);
        logger.info("Send online Message : " + simpleMessage);
        JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
        producer.send(onlineQueue, message);
    }

    public void sendToOfflineQueue(SimpleMessage simpleMessage) {
        TextMessage message = messageUtils.createTextMessage(simpleMessage);
        logger.info("Send offline Message : " + simpleMessage);
        JMSProducer producer = context.createProducer();
        producer.send(offlineQueue, message);
    }
}
```

My problem is MDB listen to multiple queues .
I want mdb only listen to onlineQueue .
How can fix this problem ?

Comment: What evidence is there that the MDB is listening to multiple queues?

Comment: I send message to offlilneQueue but online message listener want to handle that .

Comment: You are using two instances of `@JMSDestinationDefinition` to define two queues, but they both have the same `destinationName` (i.e. `application`). That seems wrong to me. Also, your MDB is using an `@ActivationConfigProperty` named `application` which also seems wrong. This should probably named `destination`.

Comment: Opss , Sorry I updated post about property name (destination) .

Comment: I confused !  you say per queue must define different destination name ?

Comment: You have two different `@JMSDestinationDefinition`. One has the `name` of `java:app/onlineQueue`, and the other has the `name` of `java:app/offlineQueue`. However, both of them have the `destinationName` of `application` which seems wrong to me. Whether you look up `java:app/onlineQueue` or `java:app/offlineQueue` in JNDI you'll get a reference to a destination named `application`.  This is almost certainly why messages sent to `java:app/offlineQueue` are picked up by the MDB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182293/discussion-between-mah454-and-justin-bertram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different `@JMSDestinationDefinition`. One has the `name` of `java:app/onlineQueue`, and the other has the name of `java:app/offlineQueue`. However, both of them have the `destinationName` of application which seems wrong to me. Whether you look up `java:app/onlineQueue` or `java:app/offlineQueue` in JNDI you'll get a reference to a destination named `application`. This is almost certainly why messages sent to `java:app/offlineQueue` are picked up by the MDB.